# How to add a LightProbe to the scene without using bpy.ops.object.lightprobe_add()?

Tags: python, objects, light, linked-data

I tried this, but it gives me an error:

```
data=bpy.data.lightprobes.new('IrradianceVolume')
bpy.data.objects.new('IrradianceVolume',data)
```

RuntimeError: Error: ID type 'LIGHT_PROBE' is not valid for an object

I want to avoid using the `bpy.ops.object.lightprobe_add()`

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are on the right track**

Check your version. The code below adds a lightprobe to the scene as expected.

Using python console

```
>>> D.lightprobes.new(
new()
BlendDataProbes.new(name, type)
Add a new probe to the main database
```

See the options for type by deliberately getting it wrong (*Or consult the docs*) **Note** somewhere between 2.80 and 2.83  `type` has been added to the [`BlendDataProbes.new(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataProbes.html#bpy.types.BlendDataProbes.new)(*current, currently 2.81*) [`BlendDataProbes.new(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.BlendDataProbes.html#bpy.types.BlendDataProbes.new)(*master currently 2.83*) method.

```
>>> D.lightprobes.new("Some Name", 'SOMETYPE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: BlendDataProbes.new(): error with argument 2, "type" -  enum "SOMETYPE" not found in ('CUBE', 'PLANAR', 'GRID')
```

Add a cube probe, link to a new object, link object to collection

```
>>> lp = D.lightprobes.new("LP", 'CUBE')
>>> foo = D.objects.new("Foo", lp)
>>> C.collection.objects.link(foo)
>>> foo
bpy.data.objects['Foo']

>>> foo.type
'LIGHT_PROBE'

>>> foo.data.type
'CUBEMAP'


>>> bpy.app.version
(2, 83, 1)
```

Comment: I find your example useful, but I did not understand correctly, is it possible to add a lightprobe in versions 2.81 without using an operator?

Comment: Works in later version than you have. Code above adds lightprobe same as using operator.  Just need the blender version where this is wired up.  @RobertGützkow is good at finding these from maniphest.

Comment: Thanks to your knowledge, therefore technically in the current official version there is no way apart from bpy.ops
So the question now is: This interesting answer of yours, at the moment I can get away with using bpy.ops (although I don't particularly like).
So if there are no solutions, I can also vote as the correct answer, because in a short time version 2.83 is released (I don't remember when).
Do you agree?

Comment: As mentioned not sure where it came in, not in yours in mine, but only aware since 2.83 (This question).  Could be in 2.82.  Up to you. If writing an addon using probes,  I'd upgrade.  . If needing code right now in 2.81, use the operator.